# Catching exception in context manager __enter__()

Tags: python, exception, python-2.7, with-statement, contextmanager

Is it possible to ensure the `__exit__()` method is called even if there is an exception in `__enter__()`?

```
>>> class TstContx(object):
...    def __enter__(self):
...        raise Exception('Oops in __enter__')
...
...    def __exit__(self, e_typ, e_val, trcbak):
...        print "This isn't running"
... 
>>> with TstContx():
...     pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __enter__
Exception: Oops in __enter__
>>>
```

**Edit**

This is as close as I could get...

```
class TstContx(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            # __enter__ code
        except Exception as e
            self.init_exc = e

        return self

    def __exit__(self, e_typ, e_val, trcbak):
        if all((e_typ, e_val, trcbak)):
            raise e_typ, e_val, trcbak

        # __exit__ code


with TstContx() as tc:
    if hasattr(tc, 'init_exc'): raise tc.init_exc

    # code in context
```

In hind sight, a context manager might have not been the best design decision

Comment: The problem is, it's not possible to skip `with` body from within `__enter__` (see [pep 377](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0377/) )

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Like this:

```
import sys

class Context(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            raise Exception("Oops in __enter__")
        except:
            # Swallow exception if __exit__ returns a True value
            if self.__exit__(*sys.exc_info()):
                pass
            else:
                raise


    def __exit__(self, e_typ, e_val, trcbak):
        print "Now it's running"


with Context():
    pass
```

To let the program continue on its merry way without executing the context block you need to inspect the context object inside the context block and only do the important stuff if `__enter__` succeeded.

```
class Context(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.enter_ok = True

    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            raise Exception("Oops in __enter__")
        except:
            if self.__exit__(*sys.exc_info()):
                self.enter_ok = False
            else:
                raise
        return self

    def __exit__(self, e_typ, e_val, trcbak):
        print "Now this runs twice"
        return True


with Context() as c:
    if c.enter_ok:
        print "Only runs if enter succeeded"

print "Execution continues"
```

As far as I can determine, you can't skip the with-block entirely. And note that this context now swallows *all* exceptions in it. If you wish not to swallow exceptions if `__enter__` succeeds, check `self.enter_ok` in `__exit__` and `return False` if it's `True`.

Comment: If there is an exception in the `__enter__` and you call `__exit__`, is there any way to break out of the `with` block in the client code?

Comment: lol I just thought about that at the same time. I updated my question with the same logic.

Comment: If the goal is to execute the __exit__ but not execute the with content, wouldn't you just do `self.__exit__(*sys.exc_info())` and then `raise` the original exception regardless of the __exit__ return value? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 13):

No. If there is the chance that an exception could occur in `__enter__()` then you will need to catch it yourself and call a helper function that contains the cleanup code.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you follow RAII (resource acquisition is initialization) and use the constructor of your context to do the potentially failing allocation. Then your `__enter__` can simply return self which should never ever raise an exception. If your constructor fails, the exception may be thrown before even entering the with context.

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print("init")
        raise Exception("booh")

    def __enter__(self):
        print("enter")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print("exit")
        return False


with Foo() as f:
    print("within with")
```

Output:

```
init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  ...
    raise Exception("booh")
Exception: booh
```

**Edit:**
Unfortunately this approach still allows the user to create "dangling" resources that wont be cleaned up if he does something like:

```
foo = Foo() # this allocates resource without a with context.
raise ValueError("bla") # foo.__exit__() will never be called.
```

I am quite curious if this could be worked around by modifying the **new** implementation of the class or some other python magic that forbids object instantiation without a with context.

Comment: +1: This answer suited my use case the best, and makes a lot of sense. Surprised it does not have more upvotes. Thanks.

Comment: Well, technically I didn't answer the question ;-)

Comment: This looks rather a bit like an anti-pattern, because it enables using a resource without actually making use of a context manager. In many situations this can lead to writing code that fails to do the proper cleanup, which is the purpose of offering a context manager. The approach may be fine in cases where the execution of `__enter__`+`__exit__` is indeed entirely optional. And admittedly the pattern is used frequently in the standard library, but that doesn't make it better ;).

Comment: Yep, that is correct:)

Answer (score 4):

[The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#cleaning-up-in-an-enter-implementation) contain an example that uses [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) for ensuring the cleanup:

> As noted in the documentation of [`ExitStack.push()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack.push), this method can be useful in cleaning up an already allocated resource if later steps in the [`__enter__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__) implementation fail.

So you would use `ExitStack()` as a wrapping context manager around the `TstContx()` context manager:

```py
from contextlib import ExitStack

with ExitStack() as stack:
    ctx = TstContx()
    stack.push(ctx)  # Leaving `stack` now ensures that `ctx.__exit__` gets called.
    with ctx:
        stack.pop_all()  # Since `ctx.__enter__` didn't raise it can handle the cleanup itself.
        ...  # Here goes the body of the actual context manager.
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `contextlib.ExitStack` (not tested):

```
with ExitStack() as stack:
    cm = TstContx()
    stack.push(cm) # ensure __exit__ is called
    with ctx:
         stack.pop_all() # __enter__ succeeded, don't call __exit__ callback
```

Or an example from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack):

```
stack = ExitStack()
try:
    x = stack.enter_context(cm)
except Exception:
    # handle __enter__ exception
else:
    with stack:
        # Handle normal case
```

See [contextlib2 on Python <3.3](http://contextlib2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 3):

if inheritance or complex subroutines are not required, you can use a shorter way:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def test_cm():
    try:
        # dangerous code
        yield  
    except Exception, err
        pass # do something
```

Comment: yes, but this would throw "generator didn't yield" in contextlib.

Comment: @thg435, reasonable, but we can wrap 'yield' with a try ... finally

Comment: that is yield in a finally block

Comment: there are plenty of workarounds, but the root of the problem is that it isn't possible to skip the entire `with` block. So even if we manage to handle exception in `enter` somehow, the block will still run, with `None` or some other rubbish as an argument.

Comment: This is not working in Python 3.9 - would be nice to see update.

Answer (score 3):

```
class MyContext:
    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            pass
            # exception-raising code
        except Exception as e:
            self.__exit__(e)

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        # clean up code ...
        if args[0]:
            raise
```

I've done it like this. It calls __exit__() with the error as the argument. If args[0] contains an error it reraises the exception after executing the clean up code.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way to implement what you want.

By design, in the Python programming language,

> **When the `__enter__` function raises an error, it means the resource to be acquired is not acquired, so there's no reason to call `__exit__`.**

It's not explained in the question that in which case would you want to call `__exit__`, but the most common case is to **make one context manager that handles two resources** ---
in other words, [compose multiple context generators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51649361/5267751).

To which, the simplest solution in my opinion is to use `@contextmanager` and a function --- in fact, I don't even know how to write a class correctly.

```py
@contextmanager
def nest_resource(a, b):
    with a as aa, b as bb:
        yield (aa, bb)
```

---

If the above is not the case for you,
you can use the recipe [Cleaning up in an `__enter__` implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#cleaning-up-in-an-enter-implementation) in the documentation.

The important part is:

```py
class ResourceManager:

    @contextmanager
    def _cleanup_on_error(self):
        with ExitStack() as stack:
            stack.push(self)
            yield
            stack.pop_all()

    def __enter__(self):
        resource = self.acquire_resource()
        with self._cleanup_on_error():
            if not self.check_resource_ok(resource):
                raise RuntimeError(msg.format(resource))
        return resource

    def __exit__(self, *exc_details):
        self.release_resource()
```

The way it works is:

- If an error happens in `acquire_resource`, then `__exit__` will **not** be called.
- If an error happens in `check_resource_ok` (or that function returns `False`), then `__exit__` will be called.
- If `__enter__` returns peacefully, then `__exit__` will not be called.

If you want to make `__exit__` always be called whenever `__enter__` fails, just put nothing before the `with` block.