# Catching an exceptions in __enter__ in the calling code in Python

Tags: python, exception, with-statement, contextmanager

Is there a way I can catch exceptions in the `__enter__` method of a context manager without wrapping the whole `with` block inside a `try`?

```
class TstContx(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        raise Exception("I'd like to catch this exception")
    def __exit__(self, e_typ, e_val, trcbak):
        pass


with TstContx():
    raise Exception("I don't want to catch this exception")
    pass
```

I know that I can catch the exception within `__enter__()` itself, but can I access that error from the function that contains the `with` statement?

On the surface the question [Catching exception in context manager `__enter__()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074847/catching-exception-in-context-manager-enter) seems to be the same thing but that question is actually about making sure that `__exit__` gets called, not with treating the `__enter__` code differently from the block that the `with` statement encloses.

...evidently the motivation should be clearer. The `with` statement is setting up some logging for a fully automated process. If the program fails before the logging is set up, then I can't rely on the logging to notify me, so I have to do something special. And I'd rather achieve the effect without having to add more indentation, like this:

```
try:
    with TstContx():
        try:
            print "Do something"
        except Exception:
            print "Here's where I would handle exception generated within the body of the with statement"
except Exception:
    print "Here's where I'd handle an exception that occurs in __enter__ (and I suppose also __exit__)"
```

Another downside to using two `try` blocks is that the code that handles the exception in `__enter__` comes after the code that handles exception in the subsequent body of the `with` block.

Comment: This doesn't sound... sane.

Comment: [my answer to the question you've linked contains the code example that allows to handle `__enter__` exceptions separately from `with`-body exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13075264/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch the exception using `try`/`except` inside of `__enter__`, then save the exception instance as an instance variable of the `TstContx` class, allowing you to access it inside of the `with` block:

```
class TstContx(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        self.exc = None
        try:
            raise Exception("I'd like to catch this exception")
        except Exception as e:
            self.exc = e 
        return self

    def __exit__(self, e_typ, e_val, trcbak):
        pass    

with TstContx() as tst:
    if tst.exc:
        print("We caught an exception: '%s'" % tst.exc)
    raise Exception("I don't want to catch this exception")
```

Output:

```
We caught an exception: 'I'd like to catch this exception'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./torn.py", line 20, in <module>
    raise Exception("I don't want to catch this exception")
Exception: I don't want to catch this exception
```

Not sure why you'd want to do this, though....

Comment: A related option would be to `return self, exception` or (in a `@contextmanager`) use `yield whatever, exception` where `exception` is `None` if no exception was raised.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) as outlined in [this doc example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#catching-exceptions-from-enter-methods) in order to check for `__enter__` errors separately:

```py
from contextlib import ExitStack

stack = ExitStack()
try:
    stack.enter_context(TstContx())
except Exception:  # `__enter__` produced an exception.
    pass
else:
    with stack:
        ...  # Here goes the body of the `with`.
```