# How should I catch exceptions raised by `with open(filename)` in Python?

Tags: python, exception, contextmanager

The act of attempting to open a file in Python can throw an exception. If I'm opening the file using the `with` statement, can I catch exceptions thrown by the `open` call and the related `__enter__` call without catching exceptions raised by the code within the `with` block?

```
try:
    with open("some_file.txt") as infile:
        print("Pretend I have a bunch of lines here and don't want the `except` below to apply to them")
        # ...a bunch more lines of code here...
except IOError as ioe:
    print("Error opening the file:", ioe)
    # ...do something smart here...
```

This question is different from [this older one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878601/catching-an-exceptions-in-enter-in-the-calling-code-in-python) in that the older one is about writing a context manager, rather than using the familiar `with open`.

Comment: Do you really want to catch exceptions thrown by `__enter__`, or do you want to catch exceptions thrown by the `open` call itself?

Comment: @BrenBarn, good point. I wasn't considering those as different, but I suppose they must be. I guess I want exceptions from either place, but I'm more concerned with whatever piece of code would be raising exception's like the `IOError`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> can I catch exceptions thrown by the open call and the related `__enter__` call without catching exceptions raised by the code within the with block?

Yes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import contextlib

stack = contextlib.ExitStack()
try:
    file = stack.enter_context(open('filename'))
except OSError as e:
    print('open() or file.__enter__() failed', e)
else:
    with stack:
        print('put your with-block here')
```

with the default `open()` function, `__enter__()` shouldn't raise any interesting exceptions and therefore the code could be simplified:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python    
try:
    file = open('filename')
except OSError as e:
    print('open() failed', e)
else:
    with file:
        print('put your with-block here')
```

Answer (score 6):

If the error has to do with opening the file (for instance, if the file doesn't exist), it will be raised by the call to `open` itself, not by `__enter__`.  In this case you can catch it by separating the `open` call from the with block:

```
try:
    myFile = open('some_file.txt')
except IOError:
    print("Oh my snakes and garters!")

with myFile:
    # do stuff

# This will be True
print(myFile.closed)
```

As the question you linked to (and other related ones) suggest, you can't really separate exceptions in `__enter__` from exceptions in the `with` block.  However, for that very reason, in most cases a context manager that tries to do complicated stuff that might raise an exception in `__enter__` is probably a fragile design anyway.  I think `file.__enter__` just returns the file (as suggested by [this page](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)), although I can't find any documentation guaranteeing this.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3, IOError is an alias of OSError. To verify, run the code:

```
IOError is OSError
---
True
```

- [PEP 3151 -- Reworking the OS and IO exception hierarchy](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/#step-1-coalesce-exception-types)

OSError is the parent class of the file I/O exceptions.

- [Exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy)

```
      +-- OSError
      |    +-- BlockingIOError
      |    +-- ChildProcessError
      |    +-- ConnectionError
      |    |    +-- BrokenPipeError
      |    |    +-- ConnectionAbortedError
      |    |    +-- ConnectionRefusedError
      |    |    +-- ConnectionResetError
      |    +-- FileExistsError
      |    +-- FileNotFoundError
      |    +-- InterruptedError
      |    +-- IsADirectoryError
      |    +-- NotADirectoryError
      |    +-- PermissionError
      |    +-- ProcessLookupError
      |    +-- TimeoutError
```

```
OSError.__subclasses__()
---
[ConnectionError,
 BlockingIOError,
 ChildProcessError,
 FileExistsError,
 FileNotFoundError,
 IsADirectoryError,
 NotADirectoryError,
 InterruptedError,
 PermissionError,
 ProcessLookupError,
 TimeoutError,
 io.UnsupportedOperation,
 signal.ItimerError,
 socket.herror,
 socket.gaierror,
 socket.timeout,
 ssl.SSLError,
 shutil.Error,
 shutil.SpecialFileError,
 shutil.ExecError,
 shutil.ReadError,
 urllib.error.URLError,
 gzip.BadGzipFile]
```

Hence, catch the OSError and check the exact class if detail is requied.

```
try:
    with open('hoge') as f:
        pass
except OSError as e:
    print(f"{type(e)}: {e}")
---
<class 'FileNotFoundError'>: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hoge'
```